# Android - Retrieve Socket from Sails

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I tried to retrieve socket from my sails server but never success. How to retrieve socket from sails server? i search every where but nothing found.

> --Update--
>
> i need some function to retrieve socket from sails which using
>   socket.io. My code was success to connect with sails server, but not
>   receieve the socket. If i implement my code for socket io only, this
>   will work, but for sails this code never retrieve the socket.

```
        try {
            JSONObject sendData = new JSONObject();
            sendData.put("url","/user/socket");
            mSocket.emit("get", sendData, new Ack() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d("AC",args[0].toString());

                }
            });
        }catch (JSONException jsonEx){
            jsonEx.printStackTrace();
        }
        //mSocket.on("/user/hello", handleIncomingMessages);
        mSocket.on("hello", handleIncomingMessages);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("Connected","Yes");
            }
        });
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("Connecting Error",args[0].toString());
            }
        });
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECTING, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("Reconnecting","Yes");
            }
        });

        mSocket.connect();
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing?

Comment: no error in  my code or log

Comment: So what's wrong?

Comment: my app never received socket from sails even after i adding function to retrieve socket. but i have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the one who downvote without any confirmation, i dunno what u want and what u after. I was solved my problem and i hope it can help someone. You just need to move ur code for handleincoming messages after retrieve respon from requesting cache to connect server.

```
try {
     JSONObject sendData = new JSONObject();
     sendData.put("url","/user/socket");
     mSocket.emit("get", sendData, new Ack() {
           @Override
           public void call(Object... args) {
              Log.d("AC",args[0].toString());
              mSocket.on("hello", handleIncomingMessages);
              }
           });
    }catch (JSONException jsonEx){
         jsonEx.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope it can help someone with same problem.